# Selecting all columns from related model with django queryset

Tags: python, django

I have a django app where I'm looking to select every column from three models.

```
Project
| - Employee
| - Task
```

Employee and Task are related to Project through a ForeignKey field.

I'm able to get the data I'm looking for using the raw method:

```
SELECT *
FROM "Project"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Employee" ON "Employee"."project_id" = "Project"."id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Task" ON "Task"."project_id" = "Project"."id";
```

However, after getting the data back I'm hoping to use django_pandas, since there is some number processing that needs to occur before the data is returned as a csv. Loading a RawQuerySet into pandas doesn't work out of the box.

There are >100 columns I need to select, and entering all of them manually into `Project.objects.values( ... )` is quite messy. How does one select all of the columns from a related model using django's QuerySet API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
projects = Project.objects.prefetch_related('employee_set', 'task_set').all()
```

And for the related fields (already pre-fetched):

```
employees_on_projects = [project.employee_set.values() for project in projects]
tasks_in_projects = [project.task_set.values() for project in projects]
```

You can have all employees and tasks lined to their respective projects by doing:

```
data = zip(projects.values(), employees_on_projects, tasks_in_projects)
```

which should work with your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

Comment: This only pulls in values from the Project object, not from the employee, nor from the task models.

Answer (score 0):

Found a programmatic way to do this. Query the meta for each table, to build a giant list that can be passed to the values method.

```
query_set_fields = []
project_fields = Project._meta.get_fields()
for i in project_fields:
    query_set_fields.append(i.name)

employee_fields = Employee._meta.get_fields()
for i in employee_fields:
    query_set_fields.append(i.name)

task_fields = Task._meta.get_fields()
for i in task_fields:
    query_set_fields.append(i.name)

qs = Project.objects.values(*query_set_fields)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(qs)
```